# on selecting school branch spinner, List of students including Name, Roll No, D.O.B, age has to be printed

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I'm trying to do a task where selecting school branch, List of students details has to get print in Listview, But i'm not getting after selecting a spinner how to get those in Listview

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

Spinner branchSpinner,organisationSpinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    branchSpinner       = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.branchId);
    organisationSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.organisationId);

    organisationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String spinnerOne = String.valueOf(organisationSpinner.getSelectedItem());
    Toast.makeText(this,spinnerOne,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(spinnerOne.contentEquals(" Delhi public School"))
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Hyderabad");
        list.add("Delhi");
        list.add("kolkata");
        list.add("Chennai");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        branchSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
    if (spinnerOne.contentEquals("chaitanya"))
    {
        List<String> list =new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Hyderabad");
        list.add("Bengaluru");
        list.add("Dharwad");
        list.add("Ameerpet");
        list.add("Mumbai");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        branchSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

StudentData.java

```
public class StudentData {
private long id;
private long RollNo;
private long date;
private long age;
private String Name;

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getRollNo() {
    return RollNo;
}

public void setRollNo(long RollNo) {
    this.RollNo = RollNo;
}

public long getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(long date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public long getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(long age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

StudentDetailsAdapter.java

```
public class StudentDetailsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private List schedule;
private Context context;

public StudentDetailsAdapter(Context context,List data)
{
    schedule = data;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    View updateView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(view == null)
    {
        updateView  = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items,null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.mName        = (TextView) updateView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.mRollNo      = (TextView) updateView.findViewById(R.id.nricId);
        viewHolder.mDob         = (TextView) updateView.findViewById(R.id.dobId);
        viewHolder.mAge         = (TextView) updateView.findViewById(R.id.ageID);

        updateView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        updateView = view;
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)updateView.getTag();
    }

    final StudentData item = (StudentData) getItem(position);

    viewHolder.mName.setText(item.getName());
    viewHolder.mRollNo.setText((int) item.getRollNo());
    viewHolder.mDob.setText((int) item.getDate());
    viewHolder.mAge.setText((int) item.getAge());


    return updateView;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView mName;
    TextView mRollNo;
    TextView mDob;
    TextView mAge;
}

}
```

Expecting Result in this format  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vng2z.png)

Comment: Can any one help me from this?

Answer (score 0):

you need add listview and inttilize it than set adpater to listview not in spinner.

Comment: I'm new to android, could you explain me how to do step by step?

Comment: look at the example :http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65

Comment: Its there... after selecting branch Total students details that i'm trying to print

Comment: You both are going in wrong way. @jaikhambhayta Please understand the problem.

Comment: Then Explain me please @DixitPanchal

Comment: friends anyone please help me from this

Answer (score 0):

you need add listview and inttilize it than set adpater to listview not in spinner.

```
 Spinner spinner;
        String path[] = {"Laptops","DesktopPC","Tablets","Add-Ons","Gaming"};
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String Laptops[] = {"Dell","Hp","Apple"};
        ListView lstView;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,listadapter;
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                for(int i=0;i<Laptops.length;i++)
                {
                    list.add(Laptops[i]);
                }
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,path);
                listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
                lstView.setAdapter(listadapter);
                spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String s = spinner.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                        list.add(s);
                        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

            }
```